# How could I properly set up this loan equation based on my code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, expression, formula

The question wants me to create 2 scenarios

1. The user accepts the dealer’s rebate offer and finances the car through his or her local credit union.

and

2. The user declines the dealer’s rebate offer but accepts the dealer’s lower financing rate.

It expects for me to use the periodic payment formula, which is: principal * rate / (1 – (rate + 1)-term) and use it to get either a monthly or annual payment.

The problem that I am having with my code I believe has something to do with my equations I am using to get annual or monthly loan payments, it for sure is not giving me the correct answer to my inputs and I do not know why.

I have tried changing the equations around several times and still no avail.

```
int main()


// these are the variables I will be using in maths for this project
double annualpayment; // what will be displayed once all is calculated annually 
double monthlypayment; // what will be displayed once all is calculated monthly
double prinicple; // amount borrowed
double rate; // interest rate
double mterm; // what the user will enter for monthly term 
double yterm; // what user will enter for yearly term
double years; // term of loan (yearly)
double month; // term of loan (monthly)
double sqrdMonth; // sqrt of term of loan (monthly)
double sqrdYear; // sqrt of term of loan (yearly)
char choice;
}
{
    cout << "Enter your principle: " << endl; // total amount borrowing
    cin >> prinicple;

    cout << "Enter your your interest rate: " << endl; // interest rate on loan
    cin >> rate;

    cout << "Will this be (M)onthly or (Y)early payment? (enter y or m)"; // declaring if it will be a monthly or yearly payment
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice = 'M') // if its monthly 
        mterm = 12; // there are 12 months within a year
    cout << "How many years will this loan be for?" << endl;
    cin >> years; // I need this information for getting the exact
    month = mterm * years;
    sqrdMonth = sqrt(month); // I need to square root the months for the periodic payment formula
    monthlypayment = (prinicple * rate) / (rate); sqrdMonth; // this is where my problem is 
                                                //  ^^^^ why is it asking me to close my equation with a ';'
    cout << "Your monthly loan payment is: ";
    cout << monthlypayment;

    if (choice = 'Y')
        yterm = 1;
    cout << "How many years will this loan be for?" << endl;
    cin >> years;
    years = yterm * years;
    sqrdYear = sqrt(years); // I need to square root the years for the periodic payment formula
    annualpayment = (prinicple * rate) / (rate); sqrdYear; // this is where my problem is 
                                        // ^^^^ why is it asking me to close my equation with a ';'
    cout << "Your annual loan payment is: ";
    cout << annualpayment;


}
```

}

I expect for the user to input the principle, rate, and length of loan then the compiler to do the math and then output the correct numbers. My actual results are negative numbers or irrational numbers.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 2):

Several mistakes

```
if (choice = 'M') // if its monthly 
    mterm = 12; // there are 12 months within a year
```

First point is that should say

```
if (choice == 'M') // if its monthly 
    mterm = 12; // there are 12 months within a year
```

In C++ we use `==` to test for equality and `=` to assign to a variable.

Even more seriously think about this

```
if (choice == 'M') // if its monthly 
    mterm = 12; // there are 12 months within a year
cout << "How many years will this loan be for?" << endl;
cin >> years; // I need this information for getting the exact
month = mterm * years;
```

Now suppose `choice` is not `'M'` what do you think the value of `mterm` will be?

The answer is that it is undefined. Yet you are using the variable in the formula two lines down. It's bad to use variables with undefined values.

It looks to me that you need to restructure your code to include more statements inside of the if statement

```
if (choice == 'M')
{
    mterm = 12; // there are 12 months within a year
    cout << "How many years will this loan be for?" << endl;
    cin >> years; // I need this information for getting the exact
    month = mterm * years;
    sqrdMonth = sqrt(month); // I need to square root the months for the periodic payment formula
    monthlypayment = (prinicple * rate) / (rate); sqrdMonth; // this is where my problem is 
                                            //  ^^^^ why is it asking me to close my equation with a ';'
    cout << "Your monthly loan payment is: ";
    cout << monthlypayment;
}
```

Finally this

```
monthlypayment = (prinicple * rate) / (rate); sqrdMonth;
```

I've no idea why you've got two semi-colons. Makes no sense to me, but I not sure what the formula should be. There's no mention of square roots in the formula in your question, so I'm not sure why you included one here.

Comment: thank you for your assistance with the if statements, I did not want to use the extra semi colons, however the program would not even run unless I put that there the formula I'd like for it to be is principal * rate / (1 – (rate + 1)-sqrt(term)), it is giving me an error code stating that a ";" is required so I did what the compiler asked, and it worked, but it is still giving me incorrect answers

Comment: `principal * rate / (1 – (rate + 1)-sqrt(term))` is not correct because you haven't declared a variable called `term`. Neither do you have a variable called `principal`. I know these may be typos but I can only go on what you type.  Also don't take compiler error messages too literally.

Comment: Based on what you've said this looks to me to be the correct formula `monthlypayment = (prinicple * rate) / (1 - (rate + 1) - sqrt (mterm));` But even that looks mathematically wrong, because the ones cancel out, +1 and -1.

Comment: excuse me John, I am a beginner. but I did make a mistake naming principle "priniciple", and term is sqrdMonth or sqrdYear relative if the user enters "m" or "y" I thought that

Comment: If you can't get it to work then post exactly what you have for the formula, cut and paste from your program, and the exact error message, again cut and paste from your program.

Comment: BTW I think you have the formula wrong. I just looked up the compound interest formula and its `prinicple * pow(1 + rate, term)`. Where `pow` means the first number raised to the power of the second number.